# How can I insert objects in SQL Server running a function in a loop? ConnectionError: .connect can not be called on a Connection in `Connecting` state

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, tedious

I'm working in a NodeJS project, this project I decided to change the way I'm doing it because this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70292789/how-can-i-insert-multiple-data-to-sql-server-in-a-loop-using-node-js-tedious) wasn't working, let me try to explain it.

I need to insert data into a SQL Server DB, so I did a function `insertOffice()` this function opens a connection using Tedious, then fetchs data to an url with data from an array `data2` to load coords, and then with this coords creates an object, then inserts this object into a DB. When inserting only one part of my `data2` array, it works, by only sendind `data[0]` it adds:

```
{
  latjson: 1,
  lonjson: 1,
  idoficina: "1",
}
```

But I want to insert both of the parts of my array, changing `data2[0]` to `data2[index]`, to be able to insert all my array, so I tried creating another function `functionLooper()`that loops `insertOffice()` to insert my data from my array `data2`.
I builded this little code to learn how to loop a function, this prints `index` that is the value I use for bringing `idoficina`.

As you can see `functionLooper()` runs the code twice, so it can read fully `data2` array, I have this little code that works with the same logic, I builded my full code using this:

```
function insertOffice(index) {
    console.log(index);
}

function functionLooper() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let response = insertOffice(i);
    }
}

functionLooper();
```

This prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

So my code it's supposed to send `index`

I'm expecting my code to loop my `insertOffice()` and being able to insert my objects, the issue is that this doesn't seems to work as I am getting this error:

```
C:\...\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:993
      throw new _errors.ConnectionError('`.connect` can not be called on a Connection in `' + this.state.name + '` state.');
            ^

ConnectionError: `.connect` can not be called on a Connection in `Connecting` state.
```

this is my code:

```
var config = {
    ....
 };

const data2 = [
    ...
 ];

var connection = new Connection(config);

function insertOffice(index) {
    console.log(index)
    connection.on("connect", function (err) {
        console.log("Successful connection");
    });
    connection.connect();

    const request = new Request(
        "EXEC SPInsert @Data1, ... ",
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Couldn't insert, " + err);
            } else {
                console.log("Inserted")
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(myObject.Id_Oficina)
    request.addParameter("Data1", TYPES.SmallInt, myObject.Id_Oficina);
    request.on("row", function (columns) {
        columns.forEach(function (column) {
            if (column.value === null) {
                console.log("NULL");
            } else {
                console.log("Product id of inserted item is " + column.value);
            }
        });
    });
    request.on("requestCompleted", function () {
        connection.close();
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
}

function functionLooper() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        let response = insertOffice(i);
    }
}

functionLooper();
```

I do not know if this is the right way to do it (looping the inserting function `insertOffice()`twice), if you know a better way to do it and if you could show me how in an example using a similar code to mine, would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you check if connection is already in an open state prior to calling connection.connect(). Perhaps setting a flag in connection.on("connect", function (err) {}.

Comment: @RossBush How can I check that mate? Because when I run my code without the loop it connects, but in the loop it doesn't

Comment: @RossBush any other way I could fix it?

Comment: Do you ever get the "Successful connection" message?

Comment: @RBarryYoung no, only when I run it without the loop

Comment: Does the `console.log(index);` happen for any of the indexes?

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes mate, my ```console.log(index);``` prints ```0 1```

Comment: Then I think that you need to create a new connection every time you enter your `insertOffice(..)` method.  It appears that it is taking a while for the connection to resolve, and you are re-entering and trying to reuse the same connection, before it has finished connecting.  So you either need to wait at some point, or else create new Connections every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could fix it, I'm sharing my code for everyone to could use it and do multiple inserts, thanks to Dan Hensby, I didn't do it his way but used part of what he said, thanks to RbarryYoung and [MichaelSun90](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/1375) who told me how, just what I did was changing my

```
var connection = new Connection(config);
```

to run inside my

```
function insertOffice(index) { ... }
```

Looking like this:

```
function insertOffice(index) {
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Heh.  You know, this is exactly what I said in the comments above "*create a new connection every time you enter your `insertOffice(..)` method.*

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching an [asynchronous problem as if it's a synchronous one](https://www.outsystems.com/blog/posts/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-programming/). You're also making your life a bit harder by mixing [event based](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-event-emitters/) async tasks with [promise based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) ones.

For example, `connection.connect()` is asynchronous (meaning that it doesn't finish all its work before the next lines of code is executed), it is only done when `connection` emits the `connect` event. So the trigger for starting the processing of your data should not be started until this event is fired.

For each of the events in your loop they are not running one at a time but all at the same time because the `fetch()` is a promise (asynchronous) it doesn't complete before the next iteration of the loop. In some cases it may have even finished before the database connection is ready, meaning the code execution has moved on to DB requests before the connection to the database is established.

To allow your code to be as manageable as possible you should aim to "promisify" the connection / requests so that you can then write an entirely promise based program, rather than mixing promises and events (which will be pretty tricky to manage - but is possible).

For example:

```js
const connection = new Connection(config);
// turn the connection event into a promise
function connect() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.once('connect', (err) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(connection));
  connection.connect()
 });
}

// insert your data once the connection is ready and then close it when all the work is done
function insertOffices() {
  connect().then((conn) => {
    // connection is ready I can do what I want
    // NB: Make sure you return a promise here otherwise the connection.close() call will fire before it's done
  }).then(() => {
    connection.close();
  });
}
```

The same approach can be taken to "promisify" the inserts.

```js
// turn a DB request into a promise
function request(conn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = new Request(...);
    request.once('error', reject);
    request.once('requestCompleted', resolve);
    conn.execSql(request);
  });
}
```

This can then be combined to perform a loop where it's executed one at a time:

```js
function doInserts() {
  return connect().then((conn) => {
    // create a "chain" of promises that execute one after the other
    let inserts = Promise.resolve();
    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        inserts = inserts.then(() => request(conn));
    }
    return inserts;
  }).then(() => connection.close())
}
```

or in parallel:

```js
function doInserts() {
  return connect().then((conn) => {
    // create an array of promises that all execute independently
    // NB - this probably won't work currently because it would need
    // multiple connections to work (rather than one)
    let inserts = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        inserts.push(request(conn));
    }
    return Promise.all(inserts);
  }).then(() => connection.close())
}
```

Comment: This is what I suspected was going on (as mentioned in my comment above), unfortunately I am not familiar enough with the technologies (both Tedious and JS events & promises) to provide this excellent answer.

Comment: @DanHensby mate, thanks for your amazing answer, but now when I try to insert only one data (before adding the loop functionallity) it gives me this error: Error: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Final state, what can it be? I did what you said until the loop

Comment: You're getting that error when you're only trying to make one request to the DB? That error is usually when you're trying to make a request before the last one is finished. I will point out that none of my above code is tested, so there may be problems with it, but it's the general approach that is required to solve your problem.

Comment: @DanHensby yep, the error is when I'm only trying to make one request :c